# Differences between query and input

Tags: php, laravel

What are differences between

`$request->query()`

And

`$request->input()` in Laravel?

Both of them return the same result.

Comment: I guess query() would only work for a GET request with parameters in the query string whereas input() works with different methods/content types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in native PHP coding.

```
$request->input() is the equivalent of $_REQUEST  //this is either querystring or form-data submission.

$request->query() is just a straight forward $_GET   //this is querystring
```

Answer (score 5):

It's mentioned directly in the official documentation:

> While the input method retrieves values from entire request payload
>   (including the query string), the query method will only retrieve
>   values from the query string:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests

Comment: Can you share soem example about `request payload` and `query string` ? May be OP is asking the same.

Comment: query string is the thing after a ? in the address: http://abc.def?xs=1&b=2 - 
the xs=1&b=2 is the query string. Request payload is the body of the HTTP request itself.

Comment: I understand about the `query string` but not sure about `HTTP request`. Also please update your comment in your answer.

Comment: You might want to google "HTTP request" or "HTTP protocol" in general. It's a very useful knowledge. Good luck!

Comment: the question wasn't about explaining http protocol itself so I will refrain from edit :)

Answer (score 5):

One important part of this two methods,

**$request->input()** :: *Can work with any HTTP verb( Ex. GET,POST,..)*

**$request->query()** :: *Can only retrieve data passed from query string( GET method )*

If you use only query string to pass data, you will get the same result for both the methods, but if you use any other HTTP method(May be with Query String values), you will find the difference.